# Custom permalink structure for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I´m using the following code to create a new post type:

```
/* Create custom post type: "Tilbud" */
register_post_type('tilbud', array(
'label' => __('Tilbud'),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '???'),
'query_var' => false,
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category'),
'supports' => array('title'),
'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_tilbud_metaboxes',
));
```

I would like the premalink of these custom posts to contain the custom post type name followed by the post category:

.../custom-post-type-name/post-category/post-title/

I´m aware that I use the rewrite argument to add a slug, but I don´t know what to write in order to insert the post type name and category name dynamically.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to implement the full solution now, but this post I wrote should get you started, http://vocecommunications.com/blog/2010/11/adding-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-types/.  You should be able to modify the filter_post_type_link() method to add the %category% permastructure tag and have it replace it with the slug from the first category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/ does exactly what you need. All you need to do with that code is remove the query_var argument and change the rewrite slug to 'tilbud' (or whatever you'd like to have in the permastruct).

Comment: I don´t want to use too many plugins. Sorry.

Comment: Then look at my plugin for ideas. I'm telling you, it does EXACTLY what you've asked about.

Comment: I´ve looked at your plugin and I can say for sure its way beyond my level of understanding ;-)

Comment: Hey John, your plug-in rocks!

Comment: @JohnPBloch The custom-post-permalinks that suggested here worked great, but now it is no longet available in the plugin repository and the plugin does not work with WP3.4.

Comment: @JohnPBloch, what if you don't want t slug at all? All I want is `mydomain.com/post-title/`

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI the plugin mentioned above is awesome. Not only do you get permalinks for custom post types, but it supports custom taxonomy too, so something like this is legit:

```
/games/%game_category%/%game%
```

Results in:

```
/games/racing/need-for-speed/
```

Good job!

(couldn't post this as a comment for some reason, sorry)

Comment: This plugin no longer works in WP3.4 and also not available in the repository. Are there other implementation ideas for this issue?

Comment: @MaorBarazany patches welcome I assume :)